# MySQLdb._exceoption.OperationalError due to Daylight Saving time

Tags: python, mysql

I can't upload my dataframe to a mySQL database. The Error message indicates that somehow there are problems with the timeshift (I am from germany), although I created a daterange in utc and I also want to save the data in utc time in my database.

Thanks for any help

```py
idx = pd.date_range(start=f'{year}-01-01', periods=len(df), freq='H', tz='utc').shift(-1, freq='H')

df.set_index(idx, inplace=True)

df.to_sql('intraday_continuous', con=engine, index=True, if_exists='replace')

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-31 02:00:00' for column 'index' at row 273")
```